# use of "=>" in cshtml pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, syntax

In many cshtml pages, I've found using:

```
@Html.LabelFor(a=>a.USERNAME)
@Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.USERNAME)
@Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.ADDRESS)
...
```

What is the meaning of doing "**a=>a.**" And how this works.

In controller page, also we get the values by doing a.USERNAME or a.ADDRESS of cshtml page. 
What is the working mechanism behind this, please explain me.

Comment: It's [lambda operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311046.aspx). There are tons of articles about how lamdba expressions work. Use Google for them.

Comment: @SonerGönül thanks for the prompt reply. Can you please explain me the working mechanism, it will be very helpful for me?